# Use value from a user control into the main form (C#)

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a Windows Form (C#) that dynamically generates copies of a User Control. Each one of the child User Controls has a timer.

I would like to sum up on the main form the overall time spent by all the User Controls (the sum of all the timers). What would be the best way to do this? How could I make the User Controls "send" their timer values to the main form?

thanks!

Comment: A timer doesn't spend any time and doesn't have a 'value'.  It just makes an event run with its Tick event.

Comment: My bad, I didn't make it clear - I call it a timer, but it's just a DateTime value that is calculated as the difference between when you click a Start and a Stop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyForm.Controls.OfType<MyCustomControlType>().Sum(c => c.TimeTakenProperty)
```

Note that if you're trying to count how long something is taking to complete you may want a System.Diagnostics.StopWatch rather than a Timer.

Comment: It's actually just a timer that users start/stop... Thx for the tip!

Comment: It pays to know your LINQ. I was trying it with `.Where()` and `.Aggregate()`, but this way is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Your user control can expose a property TimeSpent that would be summarized by the Windows Form

Inside your user control add a property TimeSpent where you return the timer value

```
public long TimeSpent 
{
    get { return getTimeSpent(); }
}
```

To calculate the time spent you need to remember how many times your timer has fired and then multiply that number for the timer interval property.

the `getTimeSpent()` function should do just that

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I am looking for... how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to implement some kind of **observer pattern**, in C# it can be easily implemented by using *delegates*. First create a delegate having the signature you want, then include an event of your delegate type, then raise the event when your user's control event occurs. Each time you create an instance of your Usercontrol associate the event you declared with some method (the observer) on your client (matching your's delegate signature).

```
public delegate void MyUserControlEvent(UserControl control, object sender, EventArgs e);

public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event MyUserControlEvent TheEvent;

    private void TimerFecha_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TheEvent != null) { TheEvent(this, sender, e); }
    }
}

public partial class SomeClient : SomeBase
{
    public SomeClient()
    {       
        MyUserControl control = new MyUserControl();
        control.TheEvent = TheListenerProcedure;
    }

    public void TheListenerProcedure(UserControl control, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* IMPLEMENT LOGIC HERE */
    }   
}
```